# Updating or refreshing a Web Access Web Part

Tags: web-part, excel, property

I am working on a project where in SharePoint, I need to have a list of report names the left site section of a page and an Excel web access web part on the right site. The functionality should allow users to click a report name, so that the Excel web access web part updates it's content with the selected report.

Unfortunately my current company doesn't allow me to code the functionality using Visual Studio /C#.

Is there another ways I can accomplish this or do something else similar?

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to update the Web part settings on the fly (which would be complicated/not recommended even with server-side code embedded in the page), why don't you:

1. Create one page per report
2. Set an Excel Viewer Web part on each of these pages
3. Set each Excel WP to dislay a given report
4. Configure the Quick Launch (lef-side) menu with links to these pages